# How can I save apples pieces that became black?

Tags: apples

Apple pieces became black very quickly. How can I save them?

Comment: Please remember: Whenever you want to ask a question, **first** use the search function and check whether we already *have* such a question. If you can’t find an existing Q/A, **then** ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apples turn brown due to contact with air and there are a couple of things (that I know) to slow down the process.

1. Toss the apples with a little bit of lemon (or lime) juice
2. Submerge them in ice water

both will retard the brown (oxidation) on apples and a lot of other fruit too.